# Website displaying gibberish occationally

Tags: php, encoding, joomla, joomla2.5

Sometimes when visiting the website in question, the website is displaying gibberish on the screen instead of the actual website.

[image: Screenshot of what is displayed]

Most of the time is is perfectly fine. This is happening intermittently and is very hard to reproduce. The site is built with Joomla 2.5.8 running PHP 5.4.4 on LiteSpeed V5.5 with MySQL 5.5.28-rel29.3.

It appears to be an encoding issue. I have checked that the server sends the correct encoding UTF-8 in the headers. But I'm not sure what else I should be checking.

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot this kind of issue is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like gzipped content

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. I will try to disable gzip compression and see if this still occurs.

Comment: What are your findings?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here. I tried disabling gzip, clearing cache and turning off cache. The problem could no longer be reproduced. Even after I turned cache and gzip back on and never had a problem thereafter. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to turn off gzip (both Joomla and server), and files compression (if you have such plugins / templates with such support).
If problem will not solve try to turn off cache.